# Google+ for A3M CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-plus, codeigniter-a3m

I'm currently running A3M for CodeIgniter which can be found here: https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M
For those who don't know, A3M is an account authentication system which utilises Facebook, OpenID, Twitter and Google.

What A3M doesn't support though is the new Google+ API found here: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php

Does anyone know of an existing solution/fork to A3M which supports the Google+ API or how I could go about adjusting the current Google Account Authentication to use the Google+ authentication instead?

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue on A3M for this on GitHub: https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M/issues/37
Follow that for any official update.